# Configure Apache to return 410 on some URLS

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a wordpress site with the following configuration for the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I want to return a 410 error for some pages that were deleted.

I have tried adding the following lines, but the continue to return 404 rather than 410:

```
RewriteRule ^/somepage\.asp$ - [G,NC]
RedirectMatch gone "/somepage\.asp$"
RedirectMatch gone "\.asp$"
RedirectMatch gone ".*\.asp$"
```

Each of those returns a 404 error rather than the desired 410.  I was testing by accessing it like this:

`www.example.com/somepage.asp`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by adding this line:

```
ErrorDocument 410 default
```

BTW: If someone wants to elaborate on why this works and add it as answer will accept it rather than accepting my own answer.